# Does guest posting affect acceptance on Google Adsense

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I'm thinking about starting guest posting to build links to my website.
If I start guest posting by copying the whole post to the other websites, will it affect my acceptance on the Google Adsense program?   I'm asking because the post could be considered a duplicate content on the other websites.

Comment: *Does guest posting affect acceptance on Google Adsense* Short answer. No. As a side note, do not do guest posting. That is a horrible thing to do these days. Very unwise.

Comment: Actually, the people take my posts and write it on their websites and some of them give a back link while others not.

Comment: I would be extremely concerned about this. Content theft is rampant, however, not everyone means harm. Having your content copied regardless of the link is something you want to police.

Comment: I'm sorry, one last question. If I want to reapply to Google Adsense, IS there any problem if I use a different email other than the one used the first time? because I want to use another account because the time zone is different And the docs say you need another account.

Comment: I have no idea about that. Sorry.